# Suppose $f$ is odd and periodic. Show that the graph of $f$ crosses the $x-$axis infinitely often.

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is odd and periodic. Show that the graph of $f$ crosses the $x-$axis infinitely often.

I don't understand the proof of this 
 solution is :

$f$ is odd $\implies f(0)=−f(0)\implies f(0)=0.$

So $f(c)=f(2c)=\cdots=0,$ also (by periodicity, where $c$ is the period)

Comment: How do you define an odd function and a periodic function?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand, this looks easy ?

Comment: What part of the proof don't you understand? As it stands, I'm not sure how we could help you besides just restating the proof.

Comment: Can I say the constant function $f(x) = 0$ is periodic? Do you count that function "crosses" the $x$-axis?

Comment: The function $f(x) = \csc x$ where it is defined and $0$ elsewhere is odd and periodic, but it does not really "cross" the $x$-axis.

Comment: As @peterwhy has already pointed out, this statement isn't even true, not necessarily. It needs additional assumptions, for example that the domain of the function is all reals.

Comment: Of course, this needn't be true if (1) $f$ is not continuous, or (2) the domain of $f$ is not connected

Comment: I don't understand why did it deduce  f(0)=−f(0)⟹f(0)=0. why f(0) =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f$ is an odd function, therefore by definition $$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ for all $x.$ 
In particular, taking $x=0,$ we get $$f(-0)=-f(0)\\f(0)=0$$

Let the period of $f$ be $c$.

Then $$f(x+c)=f(x)$$ for all $x.$ In particular, $$f(0+c)=f(0)\\f(c)=0$$
Also, $$f(c+c)=f(c)\\f(2c)=0$$
Proceeding this way $$f(nc)=0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z.$

Thus, $f$ cuts the $x-$axis infinitely often.

Comment: why f(0) = 0  because the function crosses x-axis or what ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Apply the definition of odd function to $x=0.$ $f(0)=-f(0) \implies 2f(0)=0 \implies f(0)=0$

Comment: I understood I didn't pay attention  about 2f(0)=0 Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

For any odd function, $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$. Plugging in $x = 0$ gives us $$f(0) = f(-0) = -f(0)$$so we know $f(0) = 0$. Now we know that our function is periodic with period $c$. Then $f(x) = f(x+c)$ for all $x$. From these two observations, we note that $$f(c) = f(0 + c) = f(0) = 0$$and likewise,
$$f(2c) = f(c + c) = f(c) = 0$$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be odd if $f(x)=-f(-x)$.

In particular, for $x=0$, this implies that $f(0)=-f(0)$. The only time that a number is the same as its negative in $\mathbb R$ is if it is itself zero. Hence, $f(0)=0$. Then being periodic implies that $f(x)=f(x+c)$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$ and for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Hence, $0=f(0)=f(c)=f(2c)=\dots$

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. Let us take the function

$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin x}\,,\qquad x\neq k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb Z.
$$

It is an odd function, however it does not cross the $x$-axis at any point.